# Best ways to prevent the house from termites

Tags: wood, plywood, termite, chemicals, ants

I'm thinking if I encircle the building with a rubber pipe which has holes in it.

Then I can connect the rubber pipe with a pot which has manual pump.

Then I can pour the anti termite liquid into the pot and use the manual pump to push the liquid into the rubber pipe and the chemicals can be released around the house ?

Is it a good idea ?

are there any other ideas ?

**FYI:**

I think I have to choose the chemical which will not have any bad impact on concrete. There's a thing about chemical composition of sand that acts detrimental to the concrete building such as higher chlorine content like that.

**Update:**

There is a space between my building and short wall and it has some vegetation.

Is it necessary to clear the vegetation and lay cement mortar ? so termites can't come close to the building.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you used the word "Protect".  I don't know if you have a current infestation.  If you do, you will need to get a treatment, and midigate any severe damage.  If you simply want to prevent it, get all wood away from your home.  It doesn't have to be far, 6" is sufficient.  Mulch is one of the common sources of infestations.  A common and effective way of dealing with this is to dig a trench around your home, 6" wide, and 3-4 inches deep and fill it in with some type of small rock.  If you want to use mulch, keep it beyond this rock.

Comment: I just want to prevent the house from Termites

Comment: good to know about the trenching mechanism but after a rain the sand would settle and make it worse right ?

Comment: Please find my update in the question

Comment: No. As long as you have a couple inches of depth, small stones will pack pretty well.  I did this when I lived in NJ where it rails all fall long.  No issues.

Comment: Thanks. If you could put some pictures I'd appreciate it. .

Answer (score 1):

The pros bury bait traps every couple of feet in a ring around the property. They look a lot like pop-up sprinkler heads.

Comment: Or they spray the foundation, at least in my area. May depend on exactly which species you're dealing with?

Comment: Some chemicals do have adverse effects on the foundation and rebar in the concreete , have to be wary. But I wonder how they spray the foundation during construction they lay the pipes for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Professional treatment isn't *that* expensive, is a lot better controlled than this would be, and avoids having to handle toxic chemicals myself.

Points for creativity, though...

Comment: The problem with "professional treatment" is that industry is full of scammers.  I once paid $75/mo for 6 months until I got a camera system and watched the guy put up signs and sleep in his car for a half hour.

Comment: Every industry has scammers. Get recommendations, check reviews. (Of course I wouldn't object to someone sleeping half an hour as long as they also applied the pesticide properly. I'm not paying by hour, I'm paying for job done. The job is getting done. Break time is between them and their boss.)

Comment: @mreff555, You didn't pay $75/ mo for termite treatment..you probably paid for lawn spraying service. Lawn service is full of scams, because they offer no kind of guarantee.  After termite treatment the tech has to post what chemical was used and when. Their service has some warranty protection because it involves your house.  The comparison is not fair.

Comment: @mreff555 - I don't trust the Progessional treatment , the person might dilute the actual chemical and sell off outside or it's just hard to trust as we see so many scams

Comment: If concerned, check their reputation before signing up, as you would for any other service. There are fewer scams than the news media or rumor mill would lead you to think; "they did a fine job" is not as interesting a discussion topic.